# Is there any table in Postgresql, which will tell us which table was updated or modified recently?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to load data from kafka topics to several tables in postgres. Do we have any table in postgres which will tell which table is modified or updated recently??

Comment: Have you considered adding a `last_changed` column to your tables, e.g. with a `DEFAULT NOW()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512474/

Answer (score 0):

No. You will have to collect that information yourself, fir example using triggers.